# How to download csv file from PGadmin 4

Tags: sql, excel, csv, export, pgadmin

My question is simple. I used to download csv file after doing request thanks to PgAdmin 4 but now have no choice in the "file type" and can only download with the type "ALL Files". I really need those excel files. Could you help please?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pgadmin4 - Download Query result as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306035/pgadmin4-download-query-result-as-csv)

Comment: There was a [known issue](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/2253) related to exporting CSV's that was fixed in [pgAdmin 4 v1.5](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/) (released May 19, 2017).  Which version are you running?

Comment: Sorry for that. I am running verison 2.0. But it worked until recently... Thanks

Comment: ashleedawg, the problem mentioned seems to be different

Comment: What happens when you enter a filename ending with `.csv` in the _"All Files"_ dialog?

Comment: You are so good, thank you so much. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Enter a filename ending with `.csv` in the "All Files" dialog, like:

```
c:\yourPath\yourExportFilename.csv
```